# New Build Freezing

Tags: freeze

I just fired up my new PC build with the latest Ubuntu. It'll run great for about 5 minutes and then the mouse will freeze and I have to do a hard shut down. No keyboard commands will work. What's happening? Is this a driver issue?

EDIT

I think my gpu driver was causing problems. 
I changed the settings to use the propriatary nvidia driver. Is this correct? It hasn't happened in the last 24 hours.

Here is a screen shot of $ dpkg -l *nvidia*
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/xp36x4CjvM/

Comment: No keyboard commands?  does that mean sysrq combinations don't work & kernel is down (please be specific) or do you just mean GUI/terminal/wm/dm keys?  Also what do you mean by latest Ubuntu (most people on this site treat refer to LTS only when they mean latest so again you should be specific).

Comment: I installed 19.10 yesterday. By keyboard commands I mean ESC, or CTRL ALT DEL, any combination doesn't do anything. I'm new to Linux so I'm trying to learn how to troubleshoot.

Comment: The keys you mention may not do anything & that could be very normal and means nothing.  *magic* Sysrq keys are what I'd use (I use *magic* as the wikipedia entry is pretty good to look up when you forget what those keys are; they are trapped & operated on by the linux kernel) unlike ESC CTRL+ALT+DEL which are trapped by user level programs/gui tools. See https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=617349 for some clues. If it's GUI only, ctrl+alt+F4 may work to switch to text terminal and is what I'd use firstly anyway.  (*I mentioned F4 as i use it; it could be any text terminal*)

Comment: Great I'll read up on that, thank you.

Comment: It just happened again and nothing is working. This time after an hour of use.

Answer (score 0):

You may have multiple problems.

Let's start by checking your file system, and running a memory test...

For 18.04 or newer...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdXX`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier

  - `sudo fsck -f /dev/nvme0n1p2`
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free memtest to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.

Comment: It's saying -1 is an invalid option

Comment: @Trippingbillies41 that's a lower case L

Comment: That makes much more sense. I think it may be better if I wipe the system and install the stable version. I was overzealous in installing 19.10 without knowledge of Linux. Any tips on how to start over?

Comment: @Trippingbillies41 I'd first run memtest86. Did fsck find/fix any problems? 19.10 is not a bad place to start. Let me know.

Comment: I ran fsck and got this:
fsck from util-linux 2.34
e2fsck 1.45.3 (14-Jul-2019)
/dev/nvme0n1p2 is mounted.
e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.

For some reason I am unable to create a bootable drive of the memtest86.

Comment: @Trippingbillies41 You have to run the `fsck` whilst booted to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB. How did you try and create the memtest86 flash drive?

Comment: So I have to create another ubuntu usb and boot into that? then run the memtest?

Comment: No, you don't create another Ubuntu USB if you've already got one made. This is required to do the fsck, not memtest.

Comment: I think I found the problem by looking at the logs prior to my last crash.

Is there a way to post a screen shot of the error?

Comment: @Trippingbillies41 If it's text, edit it into your original question, or paste.ubuntu.com. Screenshots (less desirable) can go to imgur.com. Crash is different than freeze. Show me `ls -al /var/crash`.

Comment: total 8\
drwxrwsrwt  2 root whoopsie 4096 Oct 17 08:30 .\
drwxr-xr-x 14 root root     4096 Oct 17 08:34 ..\


however thats not the correct date? This is what I found\

https://imgur.com/a/QDJGpW6


...I don't know how to do page breaks on this site

Comment: Edit your question (not into the comments please) and show me `sudo lshw -C display` and `dpkg -l *nvidia*` and a screenshot of `Software & Updates` Additional Drivers tab.